# Configure Postfix to reject mails with invalid DKIM signature

Tags: email, postfix, dkim

I have configured Postfix to sign my mails using OpenDKIM.
(I followed this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-dkim-with-postfix-on-debian-wheezy).)

Now I would like to configure Postfix to reject mails for domains that have DKIM configured and the mail lacks a proper signature (eg. when my own domain is used as fake sender address).

In opendkim.conf I enabled verification (`Mode sv`) and in Postfic main.conf I have

```
milter_protocol = 2
milter_default_action = accept
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:12301
```

Im mail.log I found

```
Feb 24 19:25:10 myhost postfix/cleanup[20016]: 113623DC1119: message-id=<20140623093302970001.H132BE30.southlands@example.com>
Feb 24 19:25:10 myhost opendkim[1355]: 113623DC1119: [78.90.96.5] [78.90.96.5] not internal
Feb 24 19:25:10 myhost opendkim[1355]: 113623DC1119: not authenticated
Feb 24 19:25:10 myhost opendkim[1355]: 113623DC1119: no signature data
Feb 24 19:25:10 myhost postfix/qmgr[1791]: 113623DC1119: from=<southlands515@example.dom>, size=1981, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
```

So OpenDKIM seems to have noticed that this mail isn't valid, but it didn't get rejected.

Answer (score 0):

I followed [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/587798/using-dkim-in-my-server-for-multiple-domains-websites):

```
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:12301
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:12301
```

Comment: Except for the older protocol version, I have the same. Did you actually see mails being rejected due to invalid DKIM signatures by your Postfix ? I don't.

Answer (score 0):

For the DKIM proxy to actually reject an e-mail, the source domain should have a [DKIM ADSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Author_Domain_Signing_Practices) policy record set to `discardable`. This is a safeguard not to reject messages from domains which are not signing all the messages.